# Using Rails Devise in API mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, reactjs, devise

So as you may know Rails can work as an API only, this will prevent view generations and some other stuff.
So now I installed the Devise gem but I don't know how to start working with it.
I'm using a ReactJS front end but how do I create a user for example? With the views I figured it out before but not with only json requests.

Comment: Hello Tristan, your question is too broad to give you a specific answer, so I voted to close it. And there are many good answers to your questions, of which the better ones are opinion based. You might want to be more specific on what issue you want to solve, and come with some example that can be solved.

Comment: There's a spinoff of device which you might want to look at https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Answer (score 0):

my comment being said, and vote for close being done, here's my answer to you:

if you don't use rails own views, it's fine, though that means you'll have to build manually all the basic CRUDs for each model element you'll want to expose. Or you can have a backoffice in vanilla rails that will help you manage the basic model elements, and a frontoffice communicating through the API (because you can have both).